# Try importing in android studio: https://github.com/udacity/ud839_Miwok.git

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I tried to change the grandler but I get this information.

Unable to load class 'javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema'.

This is an unexpected error. Please file a bug containing the idea.log file.

Comment: What is a "grandler"? What does this have to do with [tag:git]? (`idea.log` sounds like you may be talking about the IntelliJ IDEA IDE, for which the correct tag would be [tag:intellij-idea], but if this *is* a message from IntelliJ IDEA, it sounds like the IntelliJ folks would like you to contact them directly, not ask on StackOverflow.)

Answer (score 2):

Just put google() under repositories in buildscript and in allprojects.
Should work fine.
[see image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJddv.png)